# Flash message or alert box inside a controller if loop RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i am a new beginner in RAILS .. all i need is in the below code when the if loop is gonna get executed i need an alert box with some content.. what will be the best way to implement that? Can anyone pls help?

```
def create
     @room = Room.new(room_params)
     from = @room.fromtime
     to = @room.totime

  c=Room.where("fromtime <= ? AND totime >= ?", from, to)
  if c.exists?(:roomname => @room.roomname) 

   #   flash[:notice] = ‘Sorry room already booked.’--- not working

  else
      respond_to do |format|
      if @room.save
        format.html { redirect_to @room, notice: 'Room was successfully booked and a notification mail has sent to the admin.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @room }        
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @room.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
  end

    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

In controller file

```
flash[:notice] = "Sorry the selected room already booked."
render :new
```

in view file new.html.erb

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
<%= content_tag(:div, value, :class => "flash #{key}") %>
```

This worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

You may use either or both `flash.alert` and `flash.notice`. But I would suggest you use `flash.alert` as well (in case you don't). Thereby, the following:

```
def create
  @room = Room.new(room_params)
  from = @room.fromtime
  to = @room.totime

  c=Room.where("fromtime <= ? AND totime >= ?", from, to)
  if c.exists?(:roomname => @room.roomname)
    # Try flash[:alert] for error-like notifications
    flash[:alert] = ‘Sorry room already booked.’
    redirect_to :back # redirect back or whatever url you like
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      if @room.save
        format.html { redirect_to @room, notice: 'Room was successfully booked and a notification mail has sent to the admin.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @room }        
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @room.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
  end

end
```

Then in your views you could do something like this:

```
<div id="flash">
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class='flash <%= key %>'>
      <%= value %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Your code didn't work because the `notice: Room was successfully...` included in the line `redirect_to @room, notice...` overrides your `flash[:notice]`. If you want to display more than one flash notices at a time (use a flash loop in your views -- i.e. my view example just above), and also at the same time use something like:

```
flash[:notice] = []
flash[:notice] << 'My first notice'
flash[:notice] << 'My second notice'
flash[:alert] = []
flash[:alert] << 'My first alert'
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to add a redirect in your if block or use `flash.now[:notice]` which lets you use it immediately when rendering using `flash[:notice]` as regular.

The method is described on [RoR API site](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-now):

> This method enables you to use the flash as a central messaging system in your app. When you need to pass an object to the next action, you use the standard flash assign ([]=). When you need to pass an object to the current action, you use now, and your object will vanish when the current action is done.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to render `new` you need to use `flash.now`

```
if c.present?
  flash.now[:notice] = 'Sorry room already booked'
  render :new
else
```

Also  your from-to logic doesn't handle overlapping bookings.  Better would be...

```
 c = Room.where("fromtime <= ? AND totime >= ?", to, from)
```